# How to handle white screen and clear the previous web cache when using WebView to display a page in android?

Tags: java, android

I use Webview to load a link when user clicks on a item in a listview. At first it display a **blank screen** and loads the page. when user hits Back button and clicks on a new item in the listview, Android preloads the previously loaded page and takes a while to display the new page.

This is confusing to the user and how do i handle the blank white screen on first load and the caching problem when using webview

```
<WebView  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/webview"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        />
```

Java code :

```
 NewsListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long l) {
                // Find the current earthquake that was clicked on
                News currentNews= mAdapter.getItem(position);


                String newsUrl = currentNews.getUrl();
WebView mWebView = (WebView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.webview);
                mWebView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                mWebView.loadUrl(newsUrl);


            }
        });
```

Comment: Use WebView client the page loads in current page

Comment: i want to use webview for fast experience

Comment: Befor load the ur add progress dialog when the webviewClient page loading finsh that time   dismiss the progress dialog

Answer (score 0):

load faster? it depends on the connection speed what you can try is adding a progress bar to keep the track of it

```
  view.loadUrl(url);
            return true;

        }
        @Override
        public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode,
                String description, String failingUrl) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
             Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Oh no! " + description, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            //super.onReceivedError(view, errorCode, description, failingUrl);
        }
        @Override
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onPageFinished(view, url);

            progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
    }

    // To handle "Back" key press event for WebView to go back to previous screen.
    @Override
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) 
    {
        if ((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) && web.canGoBack()) {
            web.goBack();
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            finish();
            return true;
        }
    }
}
```